# Only one HDMI port recognized on USB-C dock

Tags: drivers, display, output, hdmi, dock-station

I've gotten my hands on a [JCD543](https://en.j5create.com/products/jcd543) and only the HDMI/DP combination port is detected on my carbon x1 5th gen running linux while the secondary HDMI and VGA port are not.

```
$ dmesg -w
[337962.676809] pci 0000:06:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[337962.676877] pci 0000:06:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.677063] pci 0000:06:00.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.677064] pci 0000:06:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.678596] pci 0000:07:00.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[337962.678670] pci 0000:07:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.678765] pci 0000:07:00.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.678766] pci 0000:07:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.678868] pci 0000:07:01.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[337962.678933] pci 0000:07:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.679019] pci 0000:07:01.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.679020] pci 0000:07:01.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.679114] pci 0000:07:02.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[337962.679179] pci 0000:07:02.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.679264] pci 0000:07:02.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.679265] pci 0000:07:02.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.679387] pci 0000:07:04.0: [8086:15d3] type 01 class 0x060400
[337962.679451] pci 0000:07:04.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.679537] pci 0000:07:04.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.679538] pci 0000:07:04.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.679660] pci 0000:06:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 07-70]
[337962.679669] pci 0000:06:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xbc000000-0xea0fffff]
[337962.679675] pci 0000:06:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x70000000-0xb9ffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.679721] pci 0000:07:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 08]
[337962.679729] pci 0000:07:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xea000000-0xea0fffff]
[337962.679779] pci 0000:07:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 09-3b]
[337962.679788] pci 0000:07:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xbc000000-0xd3efffff]
[337962.679794] pci 0000:07:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x70000000-0x8fffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.679866] pci 0000:3c:00.0: [8086:15d4] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[337962.679902] pci 0000:3c:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xd3f00000-0xd3f0ffff]
[337962.679979] pci 0000:3c:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[337962.680086] pci 0000:3c:00.0: supports D1 D2
[337962.680088] pci 0000:3c:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D2 D3hot D3cold
[337962.680140] pci 0000:3c:00.0: 8.000 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 2.5 GT/s x4 link at 0000:07:02.0 (capable of 31.504 Gb/s with 8 GT/s x4 link)
[337962.680274] pci 0000:07:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3c]
[337962.680283] pci 0000:07:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd3f00000-0xd3ffffff]
[337962.680334] pci 0000:07:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3d-70]
[337962.680342] pci 0000:07:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4000000-0xe9ffffff]
[337962.680348] pci 0000:07:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0x90000000-0xb9ffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.680376] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[337962.680394] pci 0000:07:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 09-3b] add_size 1000
[337962.680396] pci 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3c] add_size 1000
[337962.680398] pci 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3c] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[337962.680400] pci 0000:07:04.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3d-70] add_size 1000
[337962.680402] pci 0000:06:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 07-70] add_size 4000
[337962.680406] pci 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[337962.680407] pci 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[337962.680409] pci 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x4000]
[337962.680410] pci 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x4000]
[337962.680415] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[337962.680416] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[337962.680417] pci 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680419] pci 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680420] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680421] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680422] pci 0000:07:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680424] pci 0000:07:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680426] pci 0000:07:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680427] pci 0000:07:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680429] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[337962.680430] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[337962.680432] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680433] pci 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680434] pci 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680436] pci 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[337962.680437] pci 0000:07:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 08]
[337962.680444] pci 0000:07:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xea000000-0xea0fffff]
[337962.680453] pci 0000:07:01.0: PCI bridge to [bus 09-3b]
[337962.680462] pci 0000:07:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xbc000000-0xd3efffff]
[337962.680466] pci 0000:07:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0x70000000-0x8fffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.680474] pci 0000:07:02.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3c]
[337962.680479] pci 0000:07:02.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd3f00000-0xd3ffffff]
[337962.680487] pci 0000:07:04.0: PCI bridge to [bus 3d-70]
[337962.680492] pci 0000:07:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0xd4000000-0xe9ffffff]
[337962.680495] pci 0000:07:04.0:   bridge window [mem 0x90000000-0xb9ffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.680501] pci 0000:06:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 07-70]
[337962.680506] pci 0000:06:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0xbc000000-0xea0fffff]
[337962.680509] pci 0000:06:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x70000000-0xb9ffffff 64bit pref]
[337962.681659] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[337962.681721] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[337962.682851] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000000200009810
[337962.684331] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[337962.684333] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[337962.684334] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[337962.684336] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.92-gentoo-x86_64 xhci-hcd
[337962.684337] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:3c:00.0
[337962.684507] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[337962.684561] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[337962.685353] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[337962.685398] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[337962.685401] xhci_hcd 0000:3c:00.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[337962.685438] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[337962.685439] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[337962.685440] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[337962.685442] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.92-gentoo-x86_64 xhci-hcd
[337962.685443] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:3c:00.0
[337962.685539] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[337962.685547] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
[337962.884681] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
[337962.914372] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
[337963.007656] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[337963.138798] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice= 3.c3
[337963.138800] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[337963.138801] usb 3-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[337963.138802] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[337963.138802] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: DEF0123456789ABC
[337963.139599] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[337963.139772] hub 3-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[337963.262499] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[337963.276496] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice= 3.c3
[337963.276498] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[337963.276499] usb 4-1: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[337963.276500] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[337963.276501] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: DEF0123456789ABC
[337963.278397] hub 4-1:1.0: USB hub found
[337963.278609] hub 4-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[337963.845648] usb 3-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[337963.987573] usb 3-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=2817, bcdDevice=90.54
[337963.987575] usb 3-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[337963.987576] usb 3-1.3: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[337963.987576] usb 3-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[337963.988591] hub 3-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[337963.988799] hub 3-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[337964.081329] usb 4-1.3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[337964.113966] usb 4-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=0817, bcdDevice=90.54
[337964.113968] usb 4-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[337964.113969] usb 4-1.3: Product: USB3.0 Hub
[337964.113971] usb 4-1.3: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.
[337964.116090] hub 4-1.3:1.0: USB hub found
[337964.116300] hub 4-1.3:1.0: 4 ports detected
[337964.183683] usb 4-1.4: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[337964.196083] usb 4-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0711, idProduct=5601, bcdDevice=10.10
[337964.196084] usb 4-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[337964.196085] usb 4-1.4: Product: USB Station
[337964.196086] usb 4-1.4: Manufacturer: MCT Corp.
[337965.337154] usb 4-1.3.2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[337965.353570] usb 4-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0749, bcdDevice=15.39
[337965.353572] usb 4-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=2
[337965.353573] usb 4-1.3.2: Product: USB3.0 Card Reader
[337965.353574] usb 4-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Generic
[337965.353574] usb 4-1.3.2: SerialNumber: 000000001539
[337965.361051] usb-storage 4-1.3.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[337965.361266] scsi host0: usb-storage 4-1.3.2:1.0
[337965.534773] usb 4-1.3.3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[337965.547260] usb 4-1.3.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153, bcdDevice=31.00
[337965.547262] usb 4-1.3.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[337965.547263] usb 4-1.3.3: Product: USB 10/100/1000 LAN
[337965.547264] usb 4-1.3.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[337965.547264] usb 4-1.3.3: SerialNumber: 001000001
[337966.231898] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
[337966.257724] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: commit=600
[337966.367066] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 1539 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[337966.367887] scsi 0:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Generic  MassStorageClass 1539 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[337966.573482] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[337966.576811] sd 0:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[337967.093631] usb 3-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[337967.171902] usb 3-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=8888, bcdDevice= 0.01
[337967.171903] usb 3-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[337967.171904] usb 3-1.5: Product: USB Billboard Device   
[337967.171905] usb 3-1.5: Manufacturer: VIA Labs, Inc.         
[337967.171906] usb 3-1.5: SerialNumber: 0000000000000001
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Active Management Technology - SOL (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 88)
05:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
07:04.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
3c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] (rev 02)
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 6400 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   ...
DP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   3440x1440     49.99 +
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DP-1-2 disconnected 1920x1080+4480+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Ideally the video outputs would show up as `DP-2-{1,2,3}` and not just `DP-2`. It does this with other usb-C docks with multiple video outputs.

Any pointers? Hoping I won't have to end up figuring out how to write a driver for this..

Comment: Your log messages don't show the process of the outputs getting picked up. Start with `xorg.log`, and then drill down to which driver is actually responsible (there might be more in `dmesg`).

Answer (score 0):

A client had issue with JCD543. New laptop would never detect both HDMI from JCD543, only one external display came up and JCD543 showed up in Device Manager as unknown. Tried power management, clean install of driver, Win update to 10943, no luck. Client happened to have a spare VGA. Plugging it to connect the 2nd external display, all displays came up instantly, thought JCD543 still showed up as unknown.

Answer (score 0):

The dock gets *one* DisplayPort signal. This is either in Multi-Stream-Transport mode (MST) or Single-Stream (SST), but never both together. I believe telling `xrandr` to output something to `DP-1` switches to SST. I also wonder that it accepted to output simultaneously to `DP-1-1` and `DP-1-2`.

Try disabling `DP-1` and *only* drive `DP-1-*` instead. I’m not entirely sure how it works low level, but some automatism definitively failed because the monitor is made seen connected to `DP-1`, i.e. the SST-only representation.—As the other answer indicated, it might be the dock, which decides how to represent the video ports. Try unplugging all external monitors and plug in individually some monitor in each individual port. Check back on `xrandr` which `DP-1-*` finally starts turning up as connected (or if they are always reported on `DP-1` no matter the port?). Once a monitor does show up there, add further monitors and hope that the dock keeps reporting all monitors via MST.